# Consecutive Visits Calendar Possibly Broken In Meta PM SE?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I noticed that for the last 2 days the Consecutive streak calendar in my Meta PM SE profile won't load.  I can view this on PM SE.

Is this a bug?  I also noticed that the consecutive days dropped back to 1.  I'm not sure if I missed a day, which is very possible, or if there is a problem with the data which coincides with the inability to fetch the calendar.

I'll tag this as a possible bug.  If not, we can edit the tag and remove it.

Comment: Possibly a problem. My profile says that I have been a member here for 15 days, 8 visits, 1 consecutive. This means that I have been here **exactly** every other for two weeks? Doubt it!

Comment: I'm able to load your calendar on this site - are you still experiencing this issue?  If so, what browser are you using?  Do you notice any javascript errors?

Comment: @Bo it's a "hidden feature" - if you click the visited text, e.g. "8 days, 1 consecutive" in your case, you can see a calendar of when you visited the site.  I guess I should make that link more of a link!

Comment: @Jarrod: The calender actually doesn't open for meta. On the other hand, looking at the other sites '1 consecutive' seems to just mean that I wasn't here yesterday. That is definitely possible. :-)   Additional info: I use an iPad and don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a bug on the child meta sites - a fix is checked in and will be deployed tonight.

Comment: Thanks for your help!